# Why is my procedure not changing the array

Tags: arrays, delphi

I have a procedure to shift the position of the array values
The string at position 1 is supposed to take the value of the string at position 2, and the string at position 2 is supposed to take the value of the string at position 1(and so forth)
eg.

The array at the start:

```
    Pos  Value
    1      A
    2      B
    3      C
```

The array at the end (what it's supposed to become):

```
    Pos  Value
    1      B
    2      C
    3      A
```

This is the code:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls;

type
  arrRotor = array [1 .. 10] of string;

  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    RichEdit1: TRichEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }


  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure ArrayShiftRowUp(arrArrayShift: arrRotor );
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;
  j, i : integer;
  temps:string;
    arrTest: arrRotor;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.ArrayShiftRowUp(arrArrayShift: arrRotor );
begin
    for i := 1 to Length(arrArrayShift)-1 do
    begin
      tempS := arrArrayShift[i];
      arrArrayShift[i] := arrArrayShift[i + 1];
      arrArrayShift[i + 1] := tempS;
      RichEdit1.Lines.Add(arrArrayShift[i]);
    end;
   RichEdit1.Lines.Add(arrArrayShift[10]);
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
for i := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    arrTest[i]:=Chr(64+i);
  end;

  for i := 1 to 10 do
begin
  RichEdit1.Lines.Add(arrTest[i]);
end;

ArrayShiftRowUp(arrTest);

for i := 1 to 10 do
begin
  RichEdit1.Lines.Add(arrTest[i]);
end;

end;

end.
```

But for some reason, the actual array is not changing. The array parameter is changing (as evident of the display in the rich edit) but for some reason, arrTest is not changing.

What is the issue?

Comment: Static arrays are value types, not reference types. Change `procedure ArrayShiftRowUp(arrArrayShift: arrRotor );` into `procedure ArrayShiftRowUp(var arrArrayShift: arrRotor );`.

Comment: Read about pass by value and pass by reference